# .Net 4 - returning users windows login

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, active-directory

looking for some info on where to change this...
I have a .net 4 web app sitting on one box and its SQL db sitting on another.
The users windows AD login is picked up and used throughout the app with

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

If I run the app locally, I get the correct login eg "MyDomain\MyLogin",
If I hit the app on its host box the login picked up becomes "IIS APPPOOL\ASB", 
ASB being the name of the AppPool used (and the name of the app).
I really need to return "MyDomain\MyLogin", so should I use a different approach?

thanks

Comment: What kind of web app?  WindowsForms? MVC?

Comment: You need to clarify web app.  Is this ASP.NET.  When you say run locally you mean in VisualStudio?   In VisualStudio you run as your logon account.  When you hit the web site directly the app runs under pool.   If you want the logon user could implement forms authentication with AD as the user store or I think the answer from Phil will work.

Comment: Yes, its ASP.NET and Im browsing the web form from within VS 2010.

Comment: Answer from Phil?.... cant see that

Comment: Phil had and answer up but it is gone http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx  If that works I would do it over impersonate.  But I think the answer from competent_tech is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the web application to run the security context of the connected user, then you need to add the following to the `<system.web>` section of your web.config file:

```
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <identity impersonate="true" />
```

The first line tells [IIS how to authenticate users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29) and the second tells ASP.Net that you want to run the web application in the [security context of the connected user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as opposed to the security context of the IIS application pool.

Note that you can also use the [identity element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72wdk8cc%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to specify that all requests are to be run in the context of a specific user.

Comment: Hi again, on trying your fix as above, Im now getting "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" back as the user logged on to the box, rather than my windows login.

Comment: Oops! - I hadn't configured IIS authentication correctly, sorted now.